# SAP PI component naming in different environments

Tags: architecture, integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

We are in the process of integrating PI to our system landscape.

I read in the SAP Best Practices for Naming Conventions that you should include the stage/environment in your Business System Names.

ex: `BS_SOMEJMS_P`  (as P for Production)

My question is; in different components, such as Receiver Determination, you include the Business System name. Technically this means you have to create a Receiver Determination for each of your different environment? I'm used to work on a single component takings it's environment variable from a configuration file for the differentials environments.

```
BS_SOMEJMS_P | X | Y
BS_SOMEJMS_Q | X | Y
BS_SOMEJMS_D | X | Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name translation is done automatically through the transport configuration in the SLD.
CTS+ FTW!